# i want to take a user inputs and output it in my shell environment

Tags: c++, input

I want to take user input and output it on my screen.
I'm suppose to let user to key in what kind of type do they need like **Type O** for example, but my output didnt capture my **O** , just my **Type** , so is there a way for it to capture the whole line inside of the **Type** only?

a sample output of my code.

**Enter Sun Type: type k**

**Enter planets: 10**

**Sun type that was entered: type**

**No of Planets: 10**

This is only a part of my whole lengthy code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class LocationData
{   
    private:
    string sunType;
    int noOfEarthLikePlanets;
    int noOfEarthLikeMoons;
    float aveParticulateDensity;
    float avePlasmaDensity;
    public:

};
int main()
{
    int i;
    string s;
    LocationData test;
    cout<<"Enter Sun Type: ";
    cin>>s;
    test.setSunType(s);
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
    cout<<"Enter planets: ";
    cin>>i;
    test.setNoOfEarthLikePlanets(i);
    cout<<"Sun type that was entered: "<<test.getSunType();
    out<<"\nNo of Planets: "<<test.getNoOfEarthLikePlanets()<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

```
getline(cin, s);
```

reads a whole line and puts the line into the `s` variable. As you have found

```
cin >> s;
```

reads only a single word, which is why it stops at the space between **Type** and **O**.

Comment: thx :D and wanna ask do i need to clear my line after reading a string and next input is to be a int? Like in my main in my code

Comment: No, it's the other way around that you usually have to watch for. When you read an int first and a line afterward, because reading an int will not remove any following newline.

Answer (score -1):

try using `gets() / getline()` function. `cin` and `cout` ignores whitespaces by default. I don't know how to make them accept whitespace. But with above functions you will get your desired result.

Reference: [gets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/), [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)

Comment: `gets()` doesn't provide any way to limit the length of the input -- a vulnerability which was exploited by the "Internet worm" -- and its use should therefore be avoided.  Use `fgets()` instead.